# Back a page in eww browser?

Tags: eww

Is there a key-binding to go back a page in the eww web browser?

I can't find a page which lists all the key bindings.

Comment: Have you tried `<f1> b`?

Comment: @npostavs when I press `f1` the help menu opens in a new window

Answer (score 6):

You can go back with `l` (which is bound to `eww-back-url`). As with
any major mode, you can get an overview of available keybindings by
typing `C-h m` in a `eww` buffer.

The keybinding `l` is meant to be familiar to Emacs users, as it's
also used in the info browser (where it runs `Info-history-back`).